# Data Preprocessing for splitting into multiple records with AWS Lambda at AWS Data Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I need to split the data coming from AWS IoT Core by time and publish them into s3 in real-time.  
For this, I searched other stack overflow pages and also read AWS's reference page but an error occurred.


The most important thing in this task is that the data loaded **every second** would be received as json data **every minute**, and it must be stored in s3 by dividing it into time periods of 1 second. Below is an example of the data format received from IoT Core.

```json
{
   "car_id": "example1",
   "gps_data": [
      {"timestamp": 100000, "latitude": 1.0000, "longitude": 1.0000},
      {"timestamp": 100001, "latitude": 1.0001, "longitude": 1.0000},
      {"timestamp": 100002, "latitude": 1.0001, "longitude": 1.0001},
      {"timestamp": 100003, "latitude": 1.0002, "longitude": 1.0002}
   ]
}
```

The data in the above example need to be changed as follows.

```json
[
   {"car_id": "example1", "timestamp": 100000, "latitude": 1.0000, "longitude": 1.0000},
   {"car_id": "example1", "timestamp": 100001, "latitude": 1.0001, "longitude": 1.0000},
   {"car_id": "example1", "timestamp": 100002, "latitude": 1.0001, "longitude": 1.0001},
   {"car_id": "example1", "timestamp": 100003, "latitude": 1.0001, "longitude": 1.0002}
]
```

So, I implemented the code to preprocess the data as above, and modified it once more as follows, referring to that JSON must be stringified with line delimeter.

```js
let record_data_string = "";
for(let data of json_data) {
    record_data_string += JSON.stringify(data) + "\n";
}
```

```
{"car_id": "example1", "timestamp": 100000, "latitude": 1.0000, "longitude": 1.0000}
{"car_id": "example1", "timestamp": 100001, "latitude": 1.0001, "longitude": 1.0000}
{"car_id": "example1", "timestamp": 100002, "latitude": 1.0001, "longitude": 1.0001}
{"car_id": "example1", "timestamp": 100003, "latitude": 1.0001, "longitude": 1.0002}
```

After that, the data was bundled with output_record.

```js
let output = [];
let output_record = {
  recordId: record.recordId,
  result: 'Ok',
  data: Buffer.from(record_data_string, 'utf8').toString('base64')
};
output.push(output_record);
let response = {
  'records': output
};
return response;
```

As a result of checking the log through Cloudwatch, I was able to check the following response value.

```json
{
  records: [
    {
      recordId: '123456789123456789000000000',
      result: 'Ok',
      data: '...'
    }
  ]
}
```

Even when checking the data value in the response, when decoding, it was confirmed that it was the same as the record_data_string value.

However, the following error was confirmed to occur in the file in bucket/errors-metadata-extraction-failed/ s3 path.

```
{"attemptsMade":1,"arrivalTimestamp":123456789123456789,"errorCode":"DynamicPartitioning.MetadataExtractionFailed","errorMessage":"Non JSON record provided", ...
```

What additional settings are needed to solve this problem?